# 403 Forbidden on API Gateway with Custom domain's aditional domain

Tags: amazon-web-services, api, ssl, dns, gateway

I have a REST API serving behind API Gateway.

I have a Route53-hosted zone: `myAWSHostedDomain.myCompanyDomain.com`

I have also created a certificate in ACM: `myApp.myAWSHostedDomain.myCompanyDomain.com`

The certificate has an additional domain:
`myApp.myCompanyDomain.com`

The cert has been issued without any problem, both domains were validated.
In the company non-AWS-hosted zone `myCompanyDomain.com`, I have a CNAME pointing `myApp` to `myApp.myAWSHostedDomain.myCompanyDomain.com`. It resolves OK.

I have configured a Custom Domain for that API Gateway using that certificate. The name that shows is `myApp.myAWSHostedDomain.myCompanyDomain.com`. Which is fine because it's the main domain for that cert.

The problem I have is that all the requests made to `myApp.myCompanyDomain.com` fail with a **403 Forbidden** error, while those same requests on the `myApp.myAWSHostedDomain.myCompanyDomain.com` work just fine. The app code has nothing to do with it, a request for a favicon.ico behaves the same way.

The API Gateway endpoint is configured as a **Regional** one.

Could it be that API Gateway's custom domain only takes the main domain from the certificate and doesn't work with the additional ones? Is there a way to fix this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So, the problem is that the request fails with a 403 forbidden error, because API Gateway is unable to set the correct Host header, which is required for the request to succeed.

If I do:

```
curl https://myApp.myCompanyDomain.com/favicon.ico -H "Host:myApp.myAWSHostedDomain.myCompanyDomain.com"
```

Then, it works.

Hence, the options here are the following:

1. Create a DNS record in Route53 for `myApp.myCompanyDomain.com`.
2. While calling the API, add a Host header to the request, with the value set as the value for the DNS record.
3. Create a new API Gateway where the main custom domain corresponds with the one in the API Gateway: `myApp.myCompanyDomain.com` work instead of `myApp.myAWSHostedDomain.myCompanyDomain.com work`.